# xcodebuild ignoring(?) -allowProvisioningUpdates flag

Tags: ios, command-line, xcode

I'm trying to build my iOS app from command line (macOS 12.0.1, XCode command line tools 13.4.0.0.1.1651278267).

To do this, I run following command:

```
xcodebuild -workspace Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace -scheme Unity-iPhone -configuration Release -allowProvisioningUpdates -destination "platform=iOS,name=myiPhone" DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=myTeamId CODESIGN_IDENTITY=my-codesign-identity
```

However, I get the following output:

> error: There are no accounts registered with Xcode. Add your developer
> account to Xcode (in target 'Unity-iPhone' from project
> 'Unity-iPhone')
>
> error: No profiles for 'com.myCompany.myApp'
> were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning
> profiles matching 'com.myCompany.myApp'. (in target
> 'Unity-iPhone' from project 'Unity-iPhone')
> ** BUILD FAILED **

I thought `-allowProvisioningUpdates` is supposed to handle the provisioning profiles for me?

**Am I doing something wrong? How do I get this to work?**

I am hoping for a solution that I can run from the command line, since I am trying to build an automated pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can't guarantee that I didn't do any intermediate steps, but incase other people find this, what ended up working for me was to:

- make sure I unlocked the keychain right before the build command

  `security -v unlock-keychain login.keychain`
- add my DEVELOPMENT_TEAM to the command

  `xcodebuild -workspace Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace -scheme Unity-iPhone -configuration Debug -derivedDataPath ../iosBinary -allowProvisioningUpdates DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=XXXXXXXXX`

Replace XXXXXXXXX with your actual development team ID.